# Starting a Systemctl Service - Setting up uWSGI

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, systemctl

I'm trying to set up uWSGI on Ubuntu 20.04, I'm trying to create a systemctld unit file but I'm struggling to start the service.

The commands:

```
sudo systemctl start myproject
sudo systemctl status myproject
```

Output:

```
● myproject.service - uWSGI instance to serve myproject.dev
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myproject.service; enabled; vendo>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-01-28 12:58:36 UTC; 16s >
   Main PID: 19524 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

/etc/systemd/system/myproject.service

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve myproject.dev
After=network.target

[Service]
User=max
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/myproject.dev
Environment="PATH=/var/www/myproject.dev/myenv/bin"
ExecStart=/var/www/myproject.dev/myenv/bin/uwsgi --ini myproject.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I'm really stuck on this, can someone help point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by doing:

```
sudo chmod -R g+ws /var/www/myproject.dev
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/myproject.dev
```